# General expression of finite, integer sequence, containing the ceiling function

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have limited familiarity with sequences in general, so please bear with me. 
During an algorithmic problem I encountered the following sequence, which is currently not listed in OEIS. 
Describing it in a loosely way:

- for all integers $i$ from 1 up to N compute $a_i=\lceil \frac{N}{i} \rceil$. Keep $a_1$ as the first element of the sequence.
- if $a_{i+1}=\lceil \frac{N}{i+1} \rceil \neq a_i$, then keep $a_{i+1}$ as the next element in the sequence

For example, with N=32, the sequence would be: $32,16,11,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1$

With N=64 : $64,32,22,16,13,11,10,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1$

We may also observe that if the sequence consists of $m$ elements, then $b_{m} = \lceil \frac{N}{b_1} \rceil = 1$, $b_{m-1} = \lceil \frac{N}{b_2} \rceil$, $b_{m-2} = \lceil \frac{N}{b_3} \rceil$, etc.

Any thoughts on its general expression?

<sub>A bit of info on the "Why?" : Suppose that you are given a specification of performing N operations and you can distribute these N operations to k machines, each one performing a single operation at a time. The single operation itself, cannot be split. Which numbers of machine parallelism are actually meaningful? If N=8 and you set k=7 machines parallelly, for the N operations to be completed it will take the same time as k=4 machines (1 to 7 completed in the first iteration, the 8th in the second VS 1 to 4 in the first iteration, 5 to 8 in the second). You have spent more machine resources, but did not decrease the time that the total of N operations need in order to be executed. However, not only divisors of N are meaningful. For N=8, k=3 is a valid option which results in faster computation over k=2.</sub>

Comment: Your description of the sequence is too loose. If I start with $N=32$ and all integers $i$ from 1 to 32, then the first term is $a_1=\lceil \frac {32}1 \rceil = 32$, so how do you get your sequence to go from 1 to 32 (and not from 32 to 1)?

Comment: You are right, if we go from 32 downto 1, we will still get the same order of numbers. 1) Does that mean that we can not regard the above as a sequence?
2) Can we find a general expression anyway?

Comment: Whether there is a closed form or not is a separate question. The closed form is a formula depending on $i$. The way you described the sequence, $a_1$ is always $N$, not $1$. Or do you want to consider the sequence obtained after ordering the results in ascending order? This still doesn't tell you/us whether there will be a closed form, but at least let us help you solve the problem you need to solve, not a different one.

Comment: Alright, now I see what I did there. Let me edit this

Comment: I think I almost understand, given the "bit of info". Things would be much clearer if you rewrote the question to state what you really want - something like "given $N$ equal size jobs to run on $k$ identical machines, which minimal numbers of machines optimize for each given time between $1$ and $N$?" (If that's right.) Then let folks here play with how to provide a good answer. Asking us about the formula is (I think) asking an x-y question. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Well, you are right, although I did post this being more interested in the formula, rather than the actual problem. It did not even cross my mind to ask about the problem behind it. Your proposal of "N equal size jobs to run on k identical machines" does lead to several papers regarding the scheduling of jobs, that study similar, more complex problems than the one I currently have to deal with. For the time being I'll leave this question as it is. Thanks for pointing me at a fruitful direction, I found interesting things to study!